# Pytest mock pandas get_csv with chunksize

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

Does anybody know how to mock a pandas read_csv function with pytest, when it is using the `chunksize` parameter? The below functions worked well without chunksize. But when I switched to chunksize to reduce memory, it no longer mocks the return value.

```
# test.py
test_data = {
    "title": ["Tropical"],
    "year": ["2010"],
    "num_articles": ["10"],
}

def test_import_open_access(client, mocker):
    mocker.patch(
        "ingest.pd.read_csv",
        return_value=pd.DataFrame(data=test_data),
    )
    # assert stuff 

# ingest.py

def import_articles():
url = "my_url"
    for chunk in pd.read_csv(
        url, compression="gzip", keep_default_na=False, chunksize=1000
    ):
        new_records = []
        for row in chunk.to_dict(orient="records"):
            pass
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with chunk and everything to do with the fact that you are iteration over the result of `pd.read_csv` so your mock object will need to have an iterable return value

Comment: @gold_cy good point. Fixed it with `return_value=[pd.DataFrame(data=test_data)]`. Thank you!